# Verifying GUI Seed is Correct

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I setup a GUI wallet, wrote down the 25 word mnemonic seed. I loaded the block chain, which took a couple days and did a test of 2 monero.
I restored a wallet from  the 25 word mnemonic seed to verify that I wrote it down correctly. If I did write the 25 word seed down correctly, then it would accept my seed and create a new wallet file and create a new password, correct? So then I would be able to either open the new wallet file (restore the original wallet with a new password) or choose the original I set up and login with that original password?
Would that verify that my seed is written down correctly? If I'm able to restore? Restore = Correct?

Thanks

Comment: Please try and rewrite your question for clarity and succinctness.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct. Also, it's more simple to check resulting wallet address (not the integrated one, but the first one on the top under "Receive" tab) and you don't have to rescan the 2nd one (unless you want to access your "account" from that instance, too). If the wallet address is matching for both seeds then it's correct!

Comment: Thanks JollyMort, Just to verify, I checked both addresses when I clicked the "Receive" tab, and they are identical. Thus, that insures me that the mnemonic seed is written down correctly because the address under "Receive" is the same on the original wallet and the restored one. Do I have that right?

Comment: yup, that's right!